# TabLayout is not shown under Toolbar

Tags: android

This layout is incorrect. I placed Tablayout inside CollapsingToolbar to make sure it is visible:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray_background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="234dp"
        android:id="@+id/promo_detail_appbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/promo_detail_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/white"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="40dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="20dp"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedToolbarTitle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:background="@drawable/promo_background"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Королевский фарфор"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                <!-- other views here-->
            </LinearLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/promo_detail_toolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f1efef"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is how it looks now

[image: This is how it looks now]

I need Tablayout to appear under toolbar in both expanded and collapsed states. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/htab_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_design"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0.3"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Subhead.Bold"
                app:tabTextColor="#910b32"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: TabLayout is still inside AppbarLayout, I want to be under it, thank you